# concatenate or remove multiple files of a directory

Tags: shell, awk

In general for file concatenation with the same extension, we use cat `*.txt`. But in case we are in a different directory and trying to concatenate another directory's files how to do that ?
I have written a shell script which includes this statements

```
cat /home/tarakaramji/*.txt
```

the error:

```
cat /home/tarakaramji/*.txt no such file or directory
```

and the same with removing multiple files of the same extension:

```
rm /home/tarakaramji/*.txt
```

Comment: Can you add an `ls -l` output of `/home/tarakaramji/` as well ?

Comment: Seems you haven't got any txt files in your ~ directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just don't have any `.txt` files in the directory you specified, or you got the wrong directory entirely. What is happening here is that, by default, if the shell cannot find any files, it will use the literal `/home/tarakaramji/*.txt` as the argument to `cat`. Since there is no file with this name either, this is why you get the error.

You can always see exactly what files you are going to use by doing an `echo` first, e.g.

```
echo /home/tarakaramji/*.txt
```

should just display `/home/tarakaramji/*.txt`. If you set the `nullglob` shell option, this prevents the literal from being used, so effectively there would be no arguments:

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo /home/tarakaramji/*.txt
```

In this case `cat` wouldn't give an error, it would just read from `stdin`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments i have fixed it. It just because it was in a different directory!!

Comment: @tarakaramji If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone]((http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.